# Integrating a pre-existing Like button into a new Facebook page

Tags: facebook-like

I created a site and added a Facebook like button to it. Weeks later I realised that I would also like to have a Facebook page for the site. Good enough, except that when I create the FB page, it has its own Like count and its at 0. Is there anyway to integrate the existing like button with the new page?

Answer (score 0):

URL likes and Facebook PAGE like are different things. So, I don't think its possible to migrate your URL likes to your FB Page.

Comment: But it seems like once you have a facebook page, you can create a Like button from it and use it on your site(url). If that's possible then why not the other way around?